# Set values into JMS Header from Mirth Connect?

Tags: header, jms, mirth

I am using mirth connect 3.3 and having issue while setting the value into JMS header from mirth connect transformer. I am setting value like:

```
var map = Packages.org.mule.impl.RequestContext.getEventContext().getProperties();
map.put('key','value');
```

But getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call property getProperties in object [JavaPackage org.mule.impl.RequestContext]. It is not a function, it is "object".
at 22f9d2db-a1f5-4e4e-99f9-78e93d3b6135:57 (doTransform)
at 22f9d2db-a1f5-4e4e-99f9-78e93d3b6135:85 (doScript)
at 22f9d2db-a1f5-4e4e-99f9-78e93d3b6135:87
at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFi lterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.call(JavaScr iptFilterTransformer.java:154)
at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFi lterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.call(JavaScr iptFilterTransformer.java:119)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker( Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any other way to set the values into JMS header so that I can get it on sonic with the message?

Comment: The error you are getting basically tells that Mirth is not capable to find org.mule.impl.RequestContext class. First make sure that it's visible for Mirth and only then verify if you can use the map.

Comment: is there any other way Set values into JMS Header from Mirth Connect? .

Comment: This is possible or not if Yes, then how we can set values into JMS Header from Mirth Connect?.

Comment: At the current moment I don't have an environment set up to test JMS connection. So I guess it's possible but I cannot answer your question for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, have you any code/sample or any link for the same. we are stuck in this point if you have any idea please share with us.

Comment: no one have any idea about how to set the Mirth values in JMS Header.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.
https://github.com/samoanGuy7/mirth-connect-JMS-sender-with-headers/blob/main/JMS%20file%20sender%20with%20headers

This code in particular should be of interest:

```
        //Setting a property on the message(message is a data type in activemq, not just a string), not currently supported by mirth connect natively
        //https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/Message.html
        message.setType("someType");
        producer.send(message);
```

You can click on the link above to reference the documentation.